How can I use ChatGPT-4o?
I just cannot wrap my head around how to go about using ChatGPT-4o from Mathematica (14.0). I do have a paid ChatGPT Plus account with OpenAI. That gives me access to ChatGPT-4o online or through an app on my Mac.
In Mathematica, how do I actually connect to that account and then proceed?
Already in Mathematica Preferences, in the AI Settings section, on its Services tab, I was able to connect to the OpenAI service, with Model: GPT-3.5 Turbo (Jan 25, 2024). But not GPT-4o. Why not?
In a new Chat-Enabled notebook, I begin by evaluating:
openAI = ServiceConnect["OpenAI"]

But then when I ask a question in a new query cell, I get:
\[WarningSign] The server responded with the following message: 

You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing
details. For more information on this error, read the docs: 
https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.

But that can't be right: if I directly ask the same question in a browser at chatgpt.com, I do get an answer and not any message about exceeding my quota.
How does one get this to work?

Can you please check again with the new version 14.1? Looking at the blog post, it seems you should now be able to select "GPT-4 Omni".
